# getElementByClassName not working with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a three divs each with class "card". I want to perform a function when a user clicks any of the divs with this class. Simply, I can use onclick on each of the divs (and it works also) but it is rather a lengthy wok. So I ended up with this:

```
document.getElementByClassName("card").addEventListener("click", redirect);
```

But after some research I came to know that getElementByClassName returns a collection and we have to use index values to access each element with it, I finally ended with this:

```
var card = document.getElementByClassName("card");
for (var i = 0;i < card.length;i++){
    card[i].addEventListener("click", redirect);
}
```

But it is definitely not working.

I know that this is one of the most common problems, but I am not satisfied with any of the answers to related questions in the context of my problem.

Comment: The function is `getElementsByClassName` - *plural*. You then need to `forEach` over them to apply event listeners. However, you should also consider if you'd be better off delegating the event to the parent container.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a **list** of elements.

Comment: There is a beautiful feature in the browser called console. Please open it once and see if you have any errors like:  `document.getElementByClassName is not a function`

Comment: Could you please provide here `console.log(card)` ?

Comment: @palaѕн Yes, I am able to see exactly the same error.

Comment: @Pointy on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751308/getelementbyclassname-isnt-working#comment110479671_42751308) , there was a comment by a user to do the following to access an element from a class : >document.getElementsByClassName("edit")[0].innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementByClassName` it's a very subtle difference so we all stumble across it from time to time

```js
const card = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

for (let i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
  card[i].addEventListener("click", redirect);
}

function redirect(event) {
  console.log(event.target.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">Item 1</div>
<div class="card">Item 2</div>
<div class="card">Item 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working in the snippet but I can't figure out why it isn't working on my project

Comment: If you have made the change that I mentioned in the console, it could be a different error, take a look at the browser console and share the message if you find any error

Comment: Well it is working now. I put the block of code inside the body of the function redirect and it worked.